# Switch a SuperClass

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a `Class` called `Mineral` and other classes which extend this one, like `Gold`, `Iron` and `Coal`.

I'm trying to **switch** a `Mineral` **class**, in order to find out which Mineral has been **passed** through the following `addMineral` method:

```
public List<Mineral> addMineral(Mineral mineral, int amount){
    switch (mineral){
        case Gold:
            break;
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to insert the classes which extend Mineral as the cases. In fact the example above doesn't work.

Is this achievable? Is this the right way or is there a better solution?

Comment: You cannot use switch with Objects, except String. This addition is coming to Java in the future with Pattern Matching. See here: (https://youtu.be/e9eSPtpiGkA)

Comment: `if(Mineral instanceof Gold) { ... } else if(Mineral instanceof ...`

Comment: you need to check it with an `if`, for example: `if(mineral instanceof Gold) { ... }`

Comment: Alright, thanks for the claryfing guys, anyone who's posting an answer I can accept?

Comment: You didn't state why you need the switch. If possible let the mineral do the special things (or let the mineral know someone who can do it) See Open/Closed Principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot switch on arbitrary object.

You cannot switch on the class of an object.

But you can switch on the name of a class of an object:

```
switch (mineral.getClass().getName()) {
   case "some.pkg.Gold": 
       // some stuff
}
```

Or you could use `mineral.getClass().getSimpleName()` and switch on the class name without the package name, etcetera.

However, both switching on the class name and testing using `instanceof` are often "code smell".  If possible, it is better to use polymorphism rather than hard-wiring special case handling for different subclasses in other code; e.g.

```
if (mineral.hasSomeProperty()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comment already, you need to us an `if` and an `instanceof` operator like this:

```
if(mineral instanceof Gold) {
... 
}
else if(...) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the Object type by using instaceof.

**For example:**

```
if(mineral instanceof Gold) 
  System.out.println("mineral is instance of Gold"); 
else if(mineral instanceof Iron) 
  System.out.println("mineral is instance of Iron"); 
else if(mineral instanceof Coal) 
  System.out.println("mineral is instance of Coal");
```

[**Here you can find clear picture of this instanceof scenario.**](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=332)

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use switch, try this:

```
switch (object.getClass().getSimpleName()){
       case : "Gold"
              //something
              break;
       case : "Iron"
              //something
              break;
 }
```

Comment: There is no method `getClassName` on an object.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Sorry for that, I have updated the answer.